# How to get id value from a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string as below:

```
string st = [Task id=9 uniqueID=10 name=Projeect Information]
```

I want to get value of id from the above string, I've used code:

```
st.Split(' ')[1].Split('=')[1] // return 9
```

But I feel not good. I want to use regular expression to get value of id. 
Please share your ideas if you know.

Thanks

Comment: Did you know you can format code as code? Click the orange ? or look at the headers on the edit window.

Comment: Eh? If it works, it works. I don't see any reason to use regex if that solution gets you what you want. Is there any particular reason you want to use regex? Irregular strings perhaps?

Comment: Hi @tnw, Do you think about performance between using regular expression and the my current solution?

Comment: @lekimthi Rarely. I'd put it to you to prove that your method is significantly slower than a regex solution. Is there an existing performance issue that you're facing?

Comment: @tnw: I think our code will shorly and clarity if we use regular expression. This is reason that I use RegEx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=id=)\d+
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/jY1iT9)

---

C# example code ([`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
Regex.Match(@"(?<=id=)\d+", st);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
\bid=(\d+)
```

The id will be in group 1.

Answer (score 1):

use this regex `(?<=\w=)[^ ]+`

Comment: Nice alternative solution that works with other ids/values..but your lookbehind syntax is wrong: `(?<=...)`